# PDF.js examples won't run on localhost

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

Am trying to run pdf.js example on localhost and after downloading i did

```
 make server
```

But when i tried to run the examples bundled with the download i got this error

```
missing variable name
var in = i * n;
http://localhost/pdf.js/src/function.js
Line 174
```

The PDF file is successfully fetched

```
GET http://localhost/pdf.js/examples/helloworld/helloworld.pdf 200 OK 210ms
```

Is there anything i am missing as a requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Replace tne `in` variable name with another one, such as `input`.

[`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is a special keyword in JavaScript.

- Usage: `'name' in object`.
  The previous will only be true if the `'name'` property exists on the given `object`.
- Another usage is the enumeration through an object's properties [`for (name in obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).